# wgetで対象サイトのミラーを取得する

Tags: linux

wgetを使って対象のサイトからリンクされる先の全てのファイルを再帰的に取得する最も単純な方法はあるでしょうか。

```
wget <options> target
```

最も単純とは、最も少ないオプションで行う方法です。

Comment: 質問の段階で、あなたは、どこまで短いオプションで取得することができていますか？また、どのような問題に直面しましたか？例を示すと、質問された方が答えやすくなります。

Answer (score 2):

http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2014/05/02/make-offline-mirror-of-a-site-using-wget/

こちらのサイトでは

```
wget -mkEpnp http://example.org
```

というオプションでオフライン用ミラーを作成できると説明されていました。

Answer (score 0):

少し、長いけれど、取れないがあるので。各オプションは `man wget` に記述があります。

```
wget -mpEkK -nc -np -e robots=off --random-wait http://target.com
```